# How to copy value to the selected rows that meet the criteria in R dataset

Tags: r

I am new to R and have a dataset in R right now. I need to copy some values into corresponding rows (eg. in the picture [Sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLBGN.png), copy "aaa", "bbb" to the column A and B until they meet "ccc" and "ddd" and then remove empty rows afterward [post processing dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zntbr.png))

New edit: actual dataset[actual dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF9vO.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of data, it helps a lot to have actual text we can copy. I don't want to take the time to transcribe your data.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a CSV like

```
aaa,bbb
500,600,1,0.59
500,600,1,0.59
ccc,ddd
500,600,1,0.59
500,600,1,0.59
eee,fff
500,600,1,0.59
500,600,1,0.59
500,600,1,0.59
```

We can do this:

```r
txt <- readLines("something.csv")
txtgroups <- split(txt, cumsum(grepl("^[^0-9]", txt)))
txtgroups
# $`1`
# [1] "aaa,bbb"        "500,600,1,0.59" "500,600,1,0.59"
# $`2`
# [1] "ccc,ddd"        "500,600,1,0.59" "500,600,1,0.59"
# $`3`
# [1] "eee,fff"        "500,600,1,0.59" "500,600,1,0.59" "500,600,1,0.59"
unlist(lapply(txtgroups, function(z) paste0(z[1], ",", z[-1])))
#                       11                       12                       21                       22                       31                       32                       33 
# "aaa,bbb,500,600,1,0.59" "aaa,bbb,500,600,1,0.59" "ccc,ddd,500,600,1,0.59" "ccc,ddd,500,600,1,0.59" "eee,fff,500,600,1,0.59" "eee,fff,500,600,1,0.59" "eee,fff,500,600,1,0.59" 
read.csv(text = unlist(lapply(txtgroups, function(z) paste0(z[1], ",", z[-1]))), header = FALSE)
#    V1  V2  V3  V4 V5   V6
# 1 aaa bbb 500 600  1 0.59
# 2 aaa bbb 500 600  1 0.59
# 3 ccc ddd 500 600  1 0.59
# 4 ccc ddd 500 600  1 0.59
# 5 eee fff 500 600  1 0.59
# 6 eee fff 500 600  1 0.59
# 7 eee fff 500 600  1 0.59
```

Comment: Hi @r2evans, thank you for your help! I think I oversimplified my dataset so your solution works perfectly on my sample dataset (thanks again) but not on my actual dataset. I have edited my question and post a portion of  the actual dataset in my original question. I think because my data contains a mixture of string and number so the split(Text) would not work in the ideal way...